# Desktop entry changes by itself

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I am trying to add System [System Workbench](http://www.openstm32.org/System+Workbench+for+STM32) (which based on Eclipse) into dash. I placed folder in `/opt` and copied `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` (which works fine) into `~/.local/share/applications/SystemWorkbench.desktop` and it looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=System Workbench
Comment=System Workbench for STM32
Icon= /opt/SystemWorkbench/icon.xpm
Exec= /opt/SystemWorkbench/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

but after running it from dash it changes into

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=System Workbench
Exec="/opt/SystemWorkbench/plugins/fr.ac6.mcu.ide_1.12.0.201612060912/resources/project_importer/linux/System Workbench (project importer)" %U
MimeType=application/x-SystemWorkbench
Icon=SystemWorkbench
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=
Comment=
```

and I am unable to run it again. Whats going on?